# How would I get the name of a higher directory in PHP?

Tags: php

For example, I'm working on a script to check various settings and permissions. It checks `../login/includes/` to see if it's writeable, but when it displays an error, I would like to display the full URL to it.

For example, the URL to the installer would be `http://example.com/path/to/installer/index.php` and when it errors I would like it to display `http://example.com/path/to/login/includes/` rather than `http://example.com/path/to/installer/../login/includes/`

I'm aware I can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to get the `example.com` but I need to know how to get the `path/to/`

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever happen to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) in combination with `explode()` splitting on the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant ('/' in Unix, '\' in Windows) to change the path.

To get the path to your script, use the superglobal `$_SERVER` array: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`: 'The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root.' Also look into `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` ('The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'.') and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`. The easiest way to get all these at a glance is to call `phpinfo()` in your script and scroll to the `$_SERVER` vars.

If you're not using mod_rewrite, you can get the current path to your script just by reading `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. Then, split the path into it's components using `explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path)`. Small example:

```
# get path
$path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
# split path
$path_components = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
# remove last element of path
array_pop($path_components);
# rebuild path
$path = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path_components);
```

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to do it properly using this method. Can you please provide more help?

Comment: If you're not using mod_rewrite, you can get the current path to your script just by reading `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. Then, split the path into it's components using `explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path)`. I added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the complete path.

see: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Not sure why you need to use ".." instead of just using `http://example.com/path/to/login/includes`. Assuming that the `path/to` portion never changes, you could just assign that to a variable.

Comment: See, that's the thing. the `path/to/` portion WILL change. I'm working on making my script portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `dirname`:

```
var_dump(dirname('http://example.com/path/to/installer/index.php'));
var_dump(dirname(dirname('http://example.com/path/to/installer/index.php')));
var_dump(dirname(dirname(dirname('http://example.com/path/to/installer/index.php'))));
```

Outputs:

```
string(36) "http://example.com/path/to/installer"
string(26) "http://example.com/path/to"
string(23) "http://example.com/path"
```

Multiple `dirname`s are kind of messy, you can just wrap that to a function if you like.